# Estimation problem using FindMaximum

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization

**Updated**
I Edited my code with the help of answer of Okkes Dulgerci as

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[];
ClearSystemCache[]
f1[a_, b_, g_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   3 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 
     1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g))^2, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
f2[a_, b_, g_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   2 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 
     1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g)), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
f3[a_, b_, g_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 1) , {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
t1 = RandomVariate[f1[3, 3, 2], {50, 25}];
t2 = RandomVariate[f2[3, 3, 4], {50, 25}];
t3 = RandomVariate[f3[3, 3, 6], {50, 25}];
lnL[g1_?NumberQ, g2_?NumberQ, g3_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := 
  Module[{n = 25, k = 3},
   n Log[Factorial[k]] + n k Log[a] + n k Log[b] - (b + 1) ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t1[[j, i]])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t2[[j, i]])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t3[[j, i]])\)])\)\)) - (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g1\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t1[[j, i]])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g2\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t2[[j, i]])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g3\)] + 1)\)\ Log[\((1 + g3\ \*
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"t3", "[[", 
RowBox[{"j", ",", "i"}], "]]"}], ")"}], 
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"-", "b"}],
FontWeight->"Plain"]])\)])\)\))
    + ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 1)\)\ Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t1[[j, i]])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g1\)]])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 2)\) Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t2[[j, i]])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g2\)]])\)])\)\))];
Table[FindMaximum[
  lnL[g1, g2, g3, a, 
   b], {{g1, 2}, {g2, 4}, {g3, 6}, {a, 3}, {b, 3}}], {j, 1, 50}]
```

Now this code works well. But

1) It gives some time initial values as an estimates (I think when not convergent). Can we block them?

2) Whole process repeat 50 times (using table command), is correct?.

Comment: What are data1, data2, data3?

Comment: Data1, data2, and data3 are random varieties of custom distribution define above as f1,f2 and f3.

Comment: n = Length[t1]=5  why do you generate $5\times25$ data if don't use them all?

Comment: Your distributions look awfully like `BetaPrimeDistribution[]`.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci  Actually I have to estimate the parameters 10000 time. Yes here I have to used n=25, 5 is incorrect.

Comment: @J.M. It is custom distribution of reliability function based on Burr System.

Comment: @SAAN Then you should define `data1 = RandomVariate[f1[1.5, 2, 0.2], 25];`  What is your likelihood without taking log? Can you write it down?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci I edit the question, yes I found mistake in my likelihood. Now it works fine and giving reliable result. Please see my edit part of the question, I need to repeat this whole code 10000 time. Please help in this regard. And Secondly I tried your approach NMaximize, It give me results but not good results, because in NMaximize we are not using guess values.

Comment: Could this question please be made readable somehow - it unfortunately is an "eyesore" right now?

Comment: @gwr It is possible I removed before edit part? Because it is use less now?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to simplified your code. You don't need to maximize Log-likelihood, in Mathematica you can maximize likelihood. Please double check your likelihood. For this set up it does not work.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

f1[a_, b_, g_] =   
  ProbabilityDistribution[  
   3 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g -  
       1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g))^2, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];

f2[a_, b_, g_] =   
  ProbabilityDistribution[ 
   2 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g -  
       1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g)), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];

f3[a_, b_, g_] =   
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 1) , {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];

data1 = RandomVariate[f1[1.5, 2, 0.2], {5, 25}];
data2 = RandomVariate[f2[1.5, 2, 0.4], {5, 25}];
data3 = RandomVariate[f3[1.5, 2, 0.6], {5, 25}];

lnL[g1_?NumberQ, g2_?NumberQ, g3_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{n = Length[data1], k = 3},
     n Log[Factorial[k]] + n k Log[a] + n k Log[b] - (b + 1) ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((data1[\([i]\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((data2[\([i]\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((data3[\([i]\)])\)])\)\)) - (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g1\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((data1[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g2\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((data2[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g3\)] + 1)\)\ Log[\((1 + g3\ \*
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"data3", "[", 
RowBox[{"[", "i", "]"}], "]"}], ")"}], 
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"-", "b"}],
FontWeight->"Plain"]])\)])\)\))
       + ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
        1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 1)\)\ Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((data1[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g1\)]])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
        1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 2)\) Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((data2[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g2\)]])\)])\)\))]



NMaximize[ First@lnL[g1, g2, g3, a, b], {g1, g2, g3, a, b}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

**Edit** This works. I am not sure all parameters are positive!! Replace 2 by 10000 in `Table`

```
Table[f1[a_, b_, g_] = 
    ProbabilityDistribution[
      3 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 
            1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g))^2, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
 f2[a_, b_, g_] = 
    ProbabilityDistribution[
      2 a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 
            1) (1 - (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g)), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
 f3[a_, b_, g_] = 
    ProbabilityDistribution[
      a b x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^(-b))^(-a/g - 1) , {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
 t1 = RandomVariate[f1[3, 3, 2], 25];
 t2 = RandomVariate[f2[3, 3, 4], 25];
 t3 = RandomVariate[f3[3, 3, 6], 25];
 lnL[g1_?NumberQ, g2_?NumberQ, g3_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := 
    Module[{n = 25, k = 3},
      n Log[Factorial[k]] + n k Log[a] + n k Log[b] - (b + 1) ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t1[\([i]\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t2[\([i]\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
          1\), \(n\)]\((Log[\((t3[\([i]\)])\)])\)\)) - (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g1\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t1[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g2\)] + 1)\) Log[\((1 + g2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t2[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(g3\)] + 1)\)\ Log[\((1 + g3\ \*
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"t3", "[", 
RowBox[{"[", "i", "]"}], "]"}], ")"}], 
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"-", "b"}],
FontWeight->"Plain"]])\)])\)\))
        + ( \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 1)\)\ Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g1\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t1[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g1\)]])\)])\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\((\((k - 2)\) Log[\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 + g2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t2[\([i]\)])\), \(-b\)])\), 
FractionBox[\(-a\), \(g2\)]])\)])\)\))];
 NMaximize[ {lnL[g1, g2, g3, a, b], g1 > 0, g2 > 0, g3 > 0, a > 0, 
   b > 0}, {g1, g2, g3, a, b}], 2]
```

> {{-85.6331, {g1 -> 2.64838, g2 -> 3.23484, g3 -> 8.12382, 
>      a -> 3.38133, b -> 2.34444}}, {-63.0394, {g1 -> 2.14105, 
>      g2 -> 4.01569, g3 -> 9.34059, a -> 3.05859, b -> 3.05695}}}

Comment: ...well, the point of optimizing log-likelihood is that it's less likely to overflow or underflow while searching parameter space with it.

Comment: I know that. We are not sure if OP took log of likelihood correctly.